# WebSphere Portal 6.1 PortalWeb2 theme portal-navigation:urlGeneration not displaying portlets in IE

Tags: websphere-portal

I am trying to create a new custom theme for my project. I copied PortalWeb2 theme of IE and extended `sideNav.jspf` to include a jquery accordion menu.

Each menu links up to a page having some portlets

```
<ul id="accordion_menu">
  <li>
    <portal-navigation:urlGeneration contentNode="com.ccportal.home" >
      <a href="<%wpsURL.write( out );%>" >Home</a>
    </portal-navigation:urlGeneration>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This code displays portlets in Mozilla but doesn't display any portlets in IE 7. It gives some JavaScript error. Could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

If you arw using the CSA theme, sideNav.jspf will not be used( by default) to render side nav. There are certain Firefox versions which do not support CSA , so in those browsers SSA theme is used.So in your case looks like CSA theme is not working but SSA theme is working fine.
Yoy can switch to the uncompressed version of `ibmCSA.js` file and see what the exact error is.